# WMIC open file or URL

Tags: windows, cmd, command-prompt, wmic

Using `cmd.exe`, you can open a file or URL in the user’s preferred application.

```
start example.txt
start http://example.com
```

I see that WMIC can start a program

```
wmic process call create notepad.exe
```

However, can it open a file or URL, like `start`?

[Start - Windows CMD](http://ss64.com/nt/start.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This won't open the 'favored' browser, but you can get to `a` browser without the need for `start`.

```
wmic process call create "C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe www.google.com"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
wmic process call create "cmd /c start http://example.com"
```

`start` is an internal command of `cmd.exe`, so, you need to execute `cmd.exe` to reach `start` command

Comment: Thank you for the reply. However I am not asking how to reach `start`, I am asking how to do what `start` does with `wmic`.

Comment: @StevenPenny, You can't. `wmic process call create` needs to start an executable. An url (or an document) is not an executable, so, it is necessary to first determine which is the executable that needs to be called to handle the document/url/... You can first use `assoc` and/or `ftype` to find it, or if you know what the executable is you can directly call it with the url as parameter, or you can leave `start` do its work. BUT `wmic process` will only start executable files.